# Is there a free service/website/method of testing an HTML email in a specific client?

Tags: software-recommendation, e-mail

I have designed an HTML email template for a client and it works fine everywhere except, according to the client, Outlook 2013.

I don't have access to Outlook 2013 but it would be very helpful if I did. I know there are some services (like MailChimp) that provide the ability to preview your email in multiple email clients for a price but are there any free options?

Comment: I couldn't find anything ongoing however most paid services around offer a free trial which may get you enough to to test that one client.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah that's probably what I'll be doing. Just wanted to avoid having to sign up for a trial with Credit Card information as that seems to be the case with each one.

Comment: mailchimp is totally free for (I think) 2000 mails per month

Comment: Have you verified that your client has the HTML formatting option enabled?  Theres a way to toggle this on and off and that might be why its not displaying correctly

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft MailChimp only offers it for paying customers.

Comment: @maxwell I can check in with them on this. I do know just from looking at features not supported in Outlook 2013 that I was using some CSS I shouldn't be. I just would prefer now to test it before sending to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [litmus](https://litmus.com/email-testing) for testing your email. This supports a lot of clients including apple watch. here is the list of supported clients. [Mailchimp uses litmus](https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/litmus-email-rendering-tests) to render messages.

> EMAIL CLIENTS
>
> Apple Mail 8 Apple Mail 7 Lotus Notes 8.5 Lotus Notes 8 Lotus Notes 7
>   Lotus Notes 6.5 Thunderbird AOL Mail * Gmail * Google Apps * Yahoo!
>   Mail * Outlook 2016 for Mac Outlook 2013 Outlook 2011 for Mac Outlook
>   2010 Outlook 2007 Outlook 2003 Outlook 2002/XP Outlook 2000
>   Outlook.com * Office 365 * DEVICES
>
> Android 2.3 & 4.2 Gmail (Android) iPhone 6 Plus iOS 8 iPhone 6 iOS 8
>   iPhone 5s iOS 8 iPhone 5s iOS 7 iPad Mini iOS 8 iPad (retina) iOS 8
>   Windows Phone 8 BlackBerry OS 4 Text BlackBerry OS 5 HTML

They also offer a 7 day free trial. That should help you get started.

Comment: This is what I'm familiar with as well, however OP did ask for free so this may not answer the question.

Comment: The OP wants one test to check compatibility with outlook. The free trial should help with that.

Comment: I was going to use the trial with litmus but I'm not willing to sign up to the trial with my credit card. Thank you though